# Google sign in only working on the first device

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I am having trouble with google sign in, in that the first device to login has no problem but any device after that has a "failed" message. The error in log cat simply show "signInResult:failed code=10", I have searched this error and some solution I found is to make sure that firebase and google had the same SHA1 key that I have gotten from signingReport.

Just to make sure, the google side where I have to put the SHA1 key is here correct? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating.

If so I already done so and the problem still persist.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

EDIT: Here is the code handling the googlesignin by the way, after much testing it seems to only work on one device, the device afterward got a failed message.

> public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
> GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
> private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
>
>
>     // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
>     // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
>     GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
>             .requestEmail()
>             .build();
>
>     // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
>     mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
>
>     signIn();
>
> }
>
> private void signIn() {
>     Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
>     startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
>     if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
>         // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
>         // a listener.
>         Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
>         handleSignInResult(task);
>     }
> }
>
> private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
>     try {
>         GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
>         // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
>         startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
>     } catch (ApiException e) {
>         // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
>         // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
>         Log.w("Google Sign In Error", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
>         Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         final Handler handler = new Handler();
>         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>                 // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
>                 finish();
>                 System.exit(0);
>             }
>         }, 2000);
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
>     // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
>     GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
>     if(account != null) {
>         startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
>     }
>     super.onStart();
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, turns out I didn't register google sign in in the authentication tab in firebase. The reason why I didn't is that the tutorials that I followed didn't use firebase. Dumb me.

EDIT: Also that I used debug SHA1 key(which i thought was the released key) instead of the release one.